# When a node with node.master=true and node.data=false is not elected as the master node, what tasks will it undertake?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have six nodes in my elasticsearch-cluster.

```
node1 : node.master = true, node.data = false
node2 : node.master = true, node.data = false
node3 : node.master = true, node.data = false
node4 : node.master = false, node.data = true
node5 : node.master = false, node.data = true
node6 : node.master = false, node.data = false
```

If node1 is elected as the master node, I want to know what tasks will node2 and node3 take? Will they be idle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will remain mostly idle waiting their turn to be elected. They will observe all the changes to the cluster state so that when their turn comes to be elected master, they are ready to manage the cluster right away and this will happen transparently without you having to take any actions.

You might think this is a complete waste of resources, but you need to put that into perspective and think what would happen if you had only one master node and it fails for some reason, your cluster would be red and not functional any more until you get the master up and running again.

How much would your business be impacted and suffer from such a situation? If your cluster is not business critical and you can accept some downtime, then you definitely don't need two have those two master eligible nodes up and running, but since master nodes are neither memory hungry nor need a large disk space, the additional cost should be pretty much negligible.